# Get caller's caller for Ruby exception

Tags: ruby, debugging, sinatra

Right now our application is running on Heroku, and in order to save restarts and possible latency the application is designed to cache all errors and send them to stderr and just server a stale cache until the issue is resolved by another push.  This prevents application takedown...

However, the logs keep filling up excessively with entire traces which we don't want, so I built a little snippet (that is partially stolen from Rails) to parse caller and only send that line, however with errors being sent from a rescue, we get the wrong line so I was wondering how I could get the caller or the  caller or if there was a better way to handle this situation.  Here is the snippet:

```
module StdErr
  def error(message)
    file = 'Unknown'
    line = '0'

    if /^(.+?):(\d+)(?::in `(.*)')?/ =~ caller[1]
      file = $1
      line = $2
    end

    $stderr.puts "ERROR: #{message} on line #{line} of #{file}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What are you using if you aren't using Rails? Are you using Sinatra?

Comment: Yessir, we are using Sinatra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get it, you want to raise a exception with a backtrace that begins on the caller of the caller. Do it:

```
def raise_cc(*args)
  raise(*args)
rescue Exception
  # Raises the same exception, removing the last 2 items
  # from backtrace (this method and its caller). The first
  # will be the caller of the caller of this method.
  raise($!.class, $!.message, $!.backtrace[2..(-1)])
end
```

Comment: why are you using `rescue Object` ? `rescue Exception` is sufficient to catch ALL exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

`caller` returns an array and you can go deeper into the call stack by looking at it's later elements (note that you're looking at `caller[1]`)

Comment: +1 because it's not deserving of the downvote.  This does get the caller of the caller.  If you want something else, please make it clearer in the question.